# Why do I have two different return values from the queries in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hello I wonder why I have 2 different return Values. 
Here is the first query:

```
declare @currentcolumn_val varchar
declare @start integer

set @currentcolumn_val = 'state_val'
set @start =1




select @currentcolumn_val from z_skm where id = @start
```

the returned value is just "s"

Here is the second Query which gives the correct return value:

```
select state_val from z_skm where id = 1
```

This query gives me exactly what it should.

I hope you guys can help.

Cheers steven

Comment: Don't use `varchar` but f.e. `varchar(10)`.  [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Answer (score 2):

Your first query is returning a constant.  The second is returning the value of the column.

You are returning `'s`' instead of `'state_val'` because of the declaration:

```
declare @currentcolumn_val varchar;
```

You have no length on `varchar()` and in this context, it defaults to a length of 1.  *Always* use length with `varchar()` in SQL Server.

If you want the column to be dynamic, you need to use dynamic SQL:

```
declare @currentcolumn_val nvarchar(255);
declare @start integer;
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'select @currentcolumn_val from z_skm where id = @start';

set @sql = replace(@sql, '@currentcolumn_val', @currentcolumn_val);

exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@start int', @start = @start;
```

You can pass a *parameter* as an argument, but not a column or table name.

Comment: How can I store the returned value into a Variable?

Comment: @steve . . . You would use an output parameter on `sp_executesql`.  I do note that your question doesn't mention this at all.

Comment: Sorry Gordon,  I know. It looks like I had more the one Question.

Comment: @steve . . . You should ask another question as a question, rather than in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `@currentcolumn_val` simply as `varchar`, which defaults to a length of 1.

if you replace it with `declare @currentcolumn_val varchar(10)` you will see the whole value

Answer (score 0):

First you haven't given the `@currentcolumn_val` parameter a size so it is equivalent to a `VARCHAR(1)`. This means that this:

```
set @currentcolumn_val = 'state_val'
```

Is the essentially the same as:

```
set @currentcolumn_val = 's'
```

Then in your SELECT you are returning the value of that variable, not a column from the table.